# How to use grep and cut together to extract a certain text from an output using bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

Below is the output of executing two commands `ads2 svcd&` and `ps -aux|grep ads2`

```
nvidia@nvidia-desktop:~$ ads2 svcd&
[1] 4593
nvidia@nvidia-desktop:~$ ps -aux|grep ads2
nvidia    4593  0.5  0.0  39796 23864 pts/0    Sl   08:20   0:00 /opt/ads2/arm- 
linux64/bin/ads2svcd
nvidia    4603  0.0  0.0   6092   672 pts/0    S+   08:20   0:00 grep --color=auto ads2
nvidia@nvidia-desktop:~$ 
nvidia@nvidia-desktop:~$
```

the command `ads2 svcd&` runs a process related to ads2 software. with `ps -aux|grep ads2` i displayed the whole processes that contains the name "ads2".

Now What i'm trying to do is to **get the process number of the ads2** which in this example is 4593. So i wrote the follwing bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
process="$(ps -aux|grep ads  | grep 'nvidia' | cut -d' ' -f 3)" 
echo "The current ads2 process is " $process
```

The bash script outputs the following:

```
nvidia@nvidia-desktop:~$ ./test.sh 
The current ads2 process is
```

As you see the process number is not **filtered**. So what i'm i doing wrong?

thanks in advance

Comment: Try `pgrep ads2`

Comment: Reinventing `ps` tools is a common but unhappy beginner problem. Just look for existing tools which do this better, like the one suggested by Anubhava.

Comment: The concrete problem is that `cut` regards every space as a new column separator, so you are picking out the empty column between the second and third spaces in the `ps` output. Anything with more than just a couple of `grep`s should probably be refactored to Awk anyway. `ps -aux | awk '/ads/ && /nvidia/ { print $2 }'` (assuming you actually really want the PID, which is in the second column, not the third).

Comment: Just do `echo $!`???

Comment: @tripleee `nvidia@nvidia-desktop:~$ ps -aux | awk '/ads/ && /nvidia/ { print $2 }'
3755
4922
7021
7037
7122`  It prints a bunch of processes!

Comment: Then you have multiple processes which match those regexes; I just corrected the obvious error, and have not posted this as an actual attempt to answer your question. My recommendation remains to abandon doing this on your own, and use an existing tool.

Comment: @tripleee Tried the suggestion from anubhava also returned empty

Comment: @oguzismail. what does `echo $!` do?

Comment: Because the process you are looking for is apparently called `ads2svcd`. You can play around with the options to `pgrep` to match on a substring too.

Comment: Immediately after `ads2 svcd&` the variable `$!` will contain the process ID of the background process.

Comment: @tripleee. But that would print out the process ID and i want to assign it to process variable

Comment: Then use `variable=$!` instead of `echo $!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List all the processes in the current `shell` with `$$` built-in variable

```
 ps --forest -gp $$
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 3809 pts/1    Ss     0:01 bash
 4896 pts/1    T      0:00  \_ vim file.json
22965 pts/1    S+     0:00  \_ ssh dw
 3607 pts/0    Ss     0:01 bash
 2500 pts/0    R+     0:00  \_ ps --forest -gp 3607
 3327 tty2     Ssl+   0:00 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session --run-script i3
 3329 tty2     Sl+    8:12  \_ /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3
 3346 tty2     S+     0:03  \_ i3
```

Just see the `pid` of them:

```
ps -opid --forest -gp $$
  PID
 3809
 4896
22965
 3607
 2688
 3327
 3329
 3346
```

If you need to use `grep` for any reason, use `-opid,cmd` with current `shell`:

```
ps -opid,cmd -gp $$ | grep vim
 3851 grep --color=auto vim
 4896 vim file.json
```

For all, just use `-e`

```
ps -e -opid,cmd | grep vim
 4141 grep --color=auto vim
 4896 vim file.json
```

The complete one, *we have to ignore the `grep` itself*:

```
ps -e -opid,cmd | grep vim | grep -v grep |  cut -d' ' -f 2
4896
```

*Without double `grep`* using `comm` option for `ps`

```
ps -opid,comm -gp $$ | grep vim
 4896 vim
```

**of course the simplest one is `pgrep`**

```
pgrep vim
4896
```

---

NOTE for variable assignment there should NOT be any space:

```
# wrong
ads2ProcessId = $(pgrep ads2)

# right
ads2ProcessId=$(pgrep ads2)
```

Comment: Thanks. However, when i assign the result to a variable like `ads2ProcessId = $(pgrep ads2) `, it returns an error  `./test.sh: line 7: ads2process: command not found
 `. Do you know what causes the error?

Comment: Do you use space for assignment : `ads2ProcessId=$(pgrep vim)` works, with no problem

Comment: @k.jbaili Note the that command which is run is `nvidia` and not `ads2` so make sure you are looking for a right command. The name `ads2` is a sub-directory within `/opt/ads2/arm-linux64/bin/ads2svcd`

Comment: Thank you alot. it works yes its because the spaces